Expo Go EAS App Build Failing After Getting New Apple IOS Certificates to Replace Expired Ones
I'm encountering a build failure with React Native Expo EAS for an iOS app. I've recently updated my certificates due to expiration, and since then, I cannot build successfully. Here's the error message I receive:
Prepare credentials
4s


Preparing credentials
Creating keychain
Preparing credentials for target 'reflexmobile'
Getting distribution certificate fingerprint and common name
Fingerprint = "CD44CF79B491A74173F7A51B6668B2EEE7E9D628", common name = iPhone Distribution: Theory Communication & Design, Inc. (FU64QJ2JQX)
Writing distribution certificate to /var/folders/tp/1f104nqx6yq986857sbfl3yh0000gn/T/163b2b59-b24d-4a5c-b102-922fd3229013.p12
Importing distribution certificate into the keychain
Initializing provisioning profile
Validating whether the distribution certificate has been imported successfully
Destroying keychain - /var/folders/tp/1f104nqx6yq986857sbfl3yh0000gn/T/eas-build-e9293bd7-4366-4c3c-916f-4a0f6f1e6e41.keychain
Distribution certificate with fingerprint CD44CF79B491A74173F7A51B6668B2EEE7E9D628 hasn't been imported successfully

Fail build
1s


Build failed

Distribution certificate with fingerprint CD44CF79B491A74173F7A51B6668B2EEE7E9D628 hasn't been imported successfully

I'm using Linux on a Windows computer, and I do not have a Mac. In my project, I have these in my certs/ios folder:
certs/ios/distribution_cert.pem
certs/ios/full_chain.pem
certs/ios/ios_distribution.cer
certs/ios/ios_distribution.p12
certs/ios/Reflex_Mobile_2024.mobileprovision
In my Linux ca-certificate folder I have:
usr\local\share\ca-certificates\AppleWWDRCAG3.crt
usr\local\share\ca-certificates\AppleRootCA-G3.crt
I'm failing at build, using this command:
eas build --profile preview --platform ios
I've been able to build my app just fine up until now. I replaced the certificates because they expired. Apple's support told me it is basically not their problem and to check with Expo Go's support. Expo Go's support just sent me a forum link I had already seen and tried. They have since (last Friday morning) not got back to me.
Here's my package.json:
    {
      "name": "reflex-mobile",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "npx expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
        "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
        "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
        "expo": "^49.0.21",
        "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
        "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
        "expo-sqlite": "~11.3.3",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.10",
        "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.2.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
        "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
        "twrnc": "^3.3.2",
        "@expo/metro-config": "~0.10.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
      },
      "overrides": {
        "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2"
      },
      "private": true
    }

Here's my eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.6.1",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "credentialsSource": "local"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

Here's my credentials.json (password redacted for privacy):
{
  "ios": {
    "provisioningProfilePath": "certs/ios/Reflex_Mobile_2024.mobileprovision",
    "distributionCertificate": {
      "path": "certs/ios/ios_distribution.p12",
      "password": "REDACTED"
    }
  }
}

Here's my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "reflex-mobile",
    "slug": "reflex-mobile",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "FU64QJ2JQX.com.ilovetheory.reflexmobile"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "86823436-a1e8-4f9f-b218-45a355d43c65"
      }
    }
  }
}

Verified on Expo Go:
Photo of verified certs
I've tried:

Restarting my computer
Updating EXPO CLI
Updating EAS CLI
Verify the .p12 File/ Checking and Validating the .p12 Certificate File
Updating Certificates on Linux
npm update
downloaded the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority (WWDR) G3 certificate and the Apple Root CA - G3.
converted these certificates from .cer (DER format) to .pem (PEM format) using OpenSSL.
Verify the Path and Permissions
Certificate Chain Verification

Please let me know if any additional information is needed. I would appreciate any and all help and suggestions!
